# Caching different action outputs (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, optimization

We have an action 'search' that returns search items (40 per page)

and we want to cache the first 5 pages - (we a request parameter 'cur_page').

How can we do that in Rails? it seems that the standard index caching / fragment caching won't help here.

Do we need to create an index per page and redirect to it from 'search' and cache that action?

Can we do that and in the redirected action we will render the original 'search'?

Is there any better solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use fragment caching by providing a custom cache key. The key should be composed by all influential parameters like page number and search query.

```
cache('key-name') do
  ...
end
```

See [here for additional information](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#fragment-caching).

Comment: Thanks but this is good for only 1 type of output, I need to have 5 different cache outputs